# nativescript nsbuilduser directory on mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, nativescript

Running on a mac High Sierra, xcode 9 and tns doctor runs clean. What is nsbuilduser and why didn’t it install? I’m getting 10 of these errors all pointing to different things in the non-existent nsbuilduser directory… thanks much for any insights

> Building project…
>
> Xcode build…
>
> === BUILD TARGET HellowWorld OF PROJECT HellowWorld WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/9G23JDZCI6P8/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm:
>   No such file or directory

Comment: This is just a warning and you can safely dismiss it. The reason for this one to appear is because of the `tns-ios` runtime being a static library (and as such the output packet is bringing the username it was built upon)